# How can I display the response of a MailChimp form submit in a modal box instead of redirecting?

Tags: html, forms, modal-dialog, mailchimp, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a standard form for users on my site to signup for our mailing list:

```
<form class="form-stacked" action="http://coworkDF.us2.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="post">
<input class="span3" id="MERGE0" name="MERGE0" type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="e-mail">
<input type="submit" class="btn float-right mail-send" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Instead of redirecting them to the confirmation page, I'd love to display that confirmation in a modal box without leaving the page. I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap toolkit to build the site... they have a nice modal box utility but I'm not sure how to combine that with the MailChimp form.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just in general terms, you need to submit the signup request via [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) so that you stay on the current page, then extract relevant pieces from the response and use them to populate your modal.