# Display response from form submit (Mailchimp) in a modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, mailchimp

this is my first SO question, I hope someone can help!

I've got a Mailchimp form embedded on my site, customized, and I'm trying to get the response to display in a modal. I have actually succeeded in getting it into a modal, but I have not been able to get the close button to display, nor the modal overlay.

I've searched for solutions a number of places, including:

- [Modal pop up after submitting form on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822565/modal-pop-up-after-submitting-form-on-the-same-page)
- [How can I display the response of a MailChimp form submit in a modal box instead of redirecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480682/how-can-i-display-the-response-of-a-mailchimp-form-submit-in-a-modal-box-instead)

I've included jQuery on my page for this purpose, version jquery-3.2.0.min.js, but would be happy to use vanilla JS instead.

Here is the relevant part of the form HTML:

```
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
  <div class="modal-overlay closed" id="modal-overlay">
  </div>
  <div class="response modal closed" id="mce-error-response">
    <button class="close-button" id="close-button">Close Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="response modal closed" id="mce-success-response">
    <button class="close-button" id="close-button">Close Button</button>
  </div>
</div>    

<!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
  <input type="text" name="b_2e0789618f3335c1fdeae5f80_f5d18d0c88" tabindex="-1" value="">
</div>

<div class="button-heart form-submit">
  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe">
  <svg class="icon icon-heart" aria-hidden="true">
    <use xlink:href="/images/icons.svg#heart"></use>
  </svg>
</div>
```

And here is my JS, included the default MailChimp scripts:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>                  
  var modal = document.querySelector("#modal");
  var modalOverlay = document.querySelector("#modal-overlay");
  var closeButton = document.querySelector("#close-button");
  var openButton = document.querySelector("#mc-embedded-subscribe");

  openButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    modal.classList.toggle("closed");
    modalOverlay.classList.toggle("closed");
    closeButton.classList.toggle("closed");
  });

  closeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    modal.classList.toggle("closed");
    modalOverlay.classList.toggle("closed");
  });
</script>
```

And then my CSS:

```
.modal {
    display: block;
    z-index: 2000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  max-height: 100%;
  background: $main-white;
  box-shadow: $card-shadow-black;
}

.modal-overlay {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.closed {
    display: none;
}

.close-button {
    color: $third-accent;
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 2em;
    background: $main-black;
}
```

I'm also getting a console error in Chrome inspector:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):114)
```

Here is a screenshot of my current result:
[screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdERV.png)

I've found StackOverflow to be invaluable as I've been teaching myself web dev on the side over the years, I'm excited to post my first question. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: I'm going to try to answer this, but I just wanted to say that this is a really, really high-quality first question.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that while your modal has the class `modal`, it does not have the id `modal`, and as such trying to select it with the `#modal` selector will find nothing in the document, and return `null`. As properties cannot be accessed on a `null` value, an exception is thrown. Either switch your selector to `.modal` or add an `id="modal"` attribute to your modal element.

So with the following HTML:

```
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
  <div class="modal-overlay closed" id="modal-overlay">
  </div>
  <div class="response modal closed" id="mce-error-response">
    <button class="close-button" id="close-button">Close Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="response modal closed" id="modal">
    <button class="close-button" id="close-button">Close Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following JS:

```
var modal = document.querySelector("#modal");
var modalOverlay = document.querySelector("#modal-overlay");
var closeButton = document.querySelector("#close-button");
var openButton = document.querySelector("#mc-embedded-subscribe");

openButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.classList.toggle("closed");
  modalOverlay.classList.toggle("closed");
  closeButton.classList.toggle("closed");
});

closeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.classList.toggle("closed");
  modalOverlay.classList.toggle("closed");
})
```

When I click the `Subscribe` button, I see the modal pop up with only a non-functional close button within. Is this not what occurs for you?

Comment: Thanks for that @furkle - dunno how I missed it!  changed that, but now nothing displays when I submit. Previously I've had the success/error text display in the page section, or (as pictured in screenshot) in that modal. Now nothing.

Still getting console error:

'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):112)'

Comment: @MikePeiman I've updated the answer -- feel free to respond in comments.

Comment: I also note that the console error alternates between index:112 and index:106 when I do repeated submits (the closing braces of each event listener), showing that there is indeed some class toggling going on (or at least I guess there is)

Comment: reviewed your updated answer, code looks almost identical to mine, and no, I get zero visible response when I click subscribe button.

The one code discrepency I can see is in the HTML, my third inner div has the Mailchimp success id: id="mce-success-response modal".

Maybe something in the Mailchimp script is interfering?

By the way, if I enter a non-viable email address, the values I enter remain in the input fields after clicking the submit button; when I enter a viable email address, the fields clear, seeming to indicate that form validation is still functioning in the background.

Comment: Well, that's the problem. Two points: One, an element can have only a single id, so there's no need to have both `mce-success-response` and `modal` in your id attribute; Two: you're not looking for the `mce-success-response` selector in your code, you're looking for `modal`. So either update the selector in your javascript to read `mce-success-response`, or change the element's id to read `modal`.

Comment: Oh man. I've been so out of practice with web dev, I forgot you can only have one ID! D'oh! (facepalm). Thanks for reminding me my ABC's. 

Ok, I went with querying the class selector instead. Now I'm back to having the modal pop up; now I also DO have my overlay in the background (cool); but the button is being weird.

The close button DID show up for a fraction of a second in the modal, before the Mailchimp confirmation text showed up, then it disappeared. I'm wondering if this means the JS is good and we're into CSS issues. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Unfortunately the mailchimp js doesn't load for me, so I'm not sure how to go about debugging that. My recommendation, given the amount of time this has probably been off the front page, is to make another question about that issue.

Hope I've been of assistance, and best of luck!

Comment: I don't think it's the Mailchimp JS actually,  but I'll keep trying to figure this out. Thanks for the help, yes you've been of assistance!

Comment: Of course! Don't forget to accept an answer at some point, either this one, or any others that follow if they're better, so that others know what the best option to fix your problem is.

Comment: I've got it working!!! Changed too many things to list here, but the main thing was putting the two (error and success) MC divs into <p> elements, and making sure I was targeting all the correct IDs.

I also did a little magic and combined this with an SVG icon effect on clicking the submit button, WITH A DELAY before the modal popped up. I feel like a hero :)

I've accepted your answer because it was the (only) most helpful, thanks!